# My OG is too low

Tags: original-gravity

I've just done a 5 liter all grain brew. The Original specific gravity is supposed to be 1050, but its 1020. What have I done wrong, and will the brew be OK.

I thought that I had the grains properly crushed but maybe not, I'm using my homemade pasta machine mill I had the temperature as per the recipe @ 76.5 Deg C for 45 min 3 liters BIAB, with a 4 liter BIAB sparge @ 71 deg. C, it was a red ale, and I had to top up with a little water during the boil.

Comment: Your question is very very broad.  Please post the recipe and some notes on your process/equipment including mash method, sparge method and some notes on volume etc etc.

Comment: 2 row...680.5 g

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than scattering the information needed to answer it properly throughout the comments section.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you didn't get much saccarification (sugars coverted from starch) in the mash.

Causes.

1: poor crush on the grain

2: low diastatic power

3: high water grist ratio

4: mash not long enough

Edit: just did the C/F conversions. **At 169.7°F your mash was too hot and you denatured your enzymes**, causing low diastatic power and giving little saccarification.
If you still have the grist you can correct the temp to 154°ish and add enzymes to remash. Adding a couple pounds of 6-row should boost the diastatic power to get 1.050 out of a second mash.

Your comments give the water volumes but not the grains. Your gravity of 1.020 would be from less than 2lb of 2-row with proper saccarification.

Answer (score 0):

One other possibility...did you do a partial boil and top off in the fermenter?

Answer (score -1):

Possible:

1- Did you properly crash the grains?
2- What was the temperature when mashing?

Edit..

GrainWater mixture must stay between 63-68 C for 1 hour. For Bag method same applies. 73 C strike water is required. Perhaps 76.5 C is too high to release enzymes. Perhaps you added too much water. And perhaps 45 minutes should be 1 hour.

Comment: You should probably edit the question and the answer, respectively, instead of just commenting.